# jdbc4.CommunicationsException when docker run jhipster application image

Tags: docker, jhipster

my jhipster back-end application use mysql and elasticsearch, and I build a docker image using "./mvnw package -Pprod dockerfile:build -DskipTests" successfully, then I login and push the image to a private registry, then on production Centos 7, I login that registry and pull the image successfully.
Then I issue the command "Docker run iamgeid" with sudo, and have below exception:

```
2018-04-17 15:28:42.613  INFO 6 --- [           main] com.james.app.HdBackApp                  : The following profiles are active: prod
2018-04-17 15:28:50.061  INFO 6 --- [           main] com.james.app.config.WebConfigurer       : Web application configuration, using profiles: prod
2018-04-17 15:28:50.072  INFO 6 --- [           main] com.james.app.config.WebConfigurer       : Web application fully configured
2018-04-17 15:28:52.201 ERROR 6 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
```

In the official site: https://www.jhipster.tech/docker-compose/, I notice the command:

```
docker-compose -f src/main/docker/app.yml up
```

However on production, there is no such file, my question is (in my case):
1. is there some one command for all to run the back-end, including automatically pull dependencies like mysql, elasticsearch, etc
2. if no such command, what is the detail way to run the application, Note: I have set correct parameters in files (like app.yml, mysql.yml, etc) under docker folder before I build the image.

Thanks and Regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error means you application can't find a MySQL database.

In production, if you only have Docker, and no Docker Compose, you need to manually:

- start your MySQL container in a specific Docker Network, with appropriate environment var, to create the user and database
- start your Elasticsearch container in the same Network
- start your Application container in the same Network, with all specific Spring configuration, related to MySQL and Elasticsearch

It will be big `docker run...` commands.

So, it's better to have Docker-Compose too, so you have all these default configuration in this app.yml file. 
Just put the app.yml, mysql.yml and elasticsearch.yml in your production environnement. Don't forget to customize them, because we provide a basic configuration to help the users to start.

You can try the docker-compose sub generator too, using `jhipster docker-compose`. And for more advanced use, try Rancher or Kubernetes.

Comment: I copied the whole docker folder(app.yml, mysql.yml, etc) to the production, and install docker-compose, now all dependencies are pulled and ready, but remains other problems, will do some further search.

Comment: don't hesitate to add comments if you need help